# Expanding DatetimeIndex to rows in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns DateIndex, Country, and Awareness

I need to convert the DateIndex to individual date entries per row.

Input:

Country Awareness DateIndex

USA     50%      DatetimeIndex(['2017-05-01', '2017-05-02', '20...
UK      75%      DatetimeIndex(['2018-05-01', '2018-05-02', '20...
Output:
Country Awareness Date 
USA      50%       2017-05-01
USA      50%       2017-05-02
.
.
UK       75%       2018-05-01
UK       75%       2018-05-02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for pandas 0.25+ with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['USA','UK'],
                   'Awareness':['50%','75%'],
                   'Datetime':[pd.date_range('2017-05-01','2017-05-03'),
                               pd.date_range('2017-05-01','2017-05-04')]})
df = df.explode('Datetime')
print (df)
  Country Awareness   Datetime
0     USA       50% 2017-05-01
0     USA       50% 2017-05-02
0     USA       50% 2017-05-03
1      UK       75% 2017-05-01
1      UK       75% 2017-05-02
1      UK       75% 2017-05-03
1      UK       75% 2017-05-04
```

Comment: Datetime is of type: pandas.DatetimeIndex  .  I am now getting AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: @user2419259 - Because lower version of pandas like `0.25+`, is possible upgrade?